# Wrong id and gid running /system/bin/sdcard

Tags: sd-card, mount, ext4

I am trying to use my ext4 sdcard properly in Stock rooted Android 4.4.4.
For this, I run

```
mount -rw -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1
```

and then

```
/system/bin/sdcard -u 1023 -g 1023 -w 1023 /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 /storage/sdcard1
```

I also tried

```
/system/bin/sdcard /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 /storage/sdcard1 1023 1023
```

The problem is that the ownership of the tree created in `/storage/sdcard1` is then 0.1015 instead of 1023.1023 (??), so I have permission problems...

Any idea why the `/system/bin/sdcard` command is not obeying the ownership flags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
The solution is here: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config.html

> "For Android releases 4.3 and later, the various fstab files used by
>   init, vold and recovery were unified in the /fstab. file. For
>   external storage volumes that are managed by vold, the entries should
>   have the following format:"

```
 <src> <mnt_point> <type> <mnt_flags> <fs_mgr_flags>
```

> "...Devices may provide external storage by emulating a
>   case-insensitive, permissionless filesystem backed by internal
>   storage. One possible implementation is provided by the FUSE daemon in
>   system/core/sdcard, which can be added as a device-specific init.rc
>   service:"

```
# virtual sdcard daemon running as media_rw (1023)
service sdcard /system/bin/sdcard <source_path> <dest_path> 1023 1023
    class late_start
```